# How to improve a spatial raster map using ggplot when compared to spplot?

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, spatial, raster

How can I improve the legend of spatial raster map plot using ggplot when compared to a spplot() legend?

I would like plot spatial maps using ggplot() instead of ssplot() however there are a few things that I would like to improve when compared to the spplot:

1. create a ggplot legend that goes from small (bottom) to large values (top)
2. Have the breaks in the ggplot legend similar to the ssplot() legend so that I know what the boundaries are of each color.

---

```
## load packages
require(raster)
require(ggplot2)
require(rgdal)
require(RColorBrewer)
set.seed(1)

r <- raster(xmn=-110, xmx=-90, ymn=40, ymx=60, ncols=40, nrows=40,
          crs="+proj=lcc +lat_1=48 +lat_2=33 +lon_0=-100
+ellps=WGS84")
r <- setValues(r,matrix(rnorm(1600, mean=0.4,sd=0.2))) 

## 1. spatial map with spplot
cuts <-seq(minValue(r),maxValue(r),length.out=8)
cuts = round(cuts,digits=2)
col.regions = brewer.pal(length(cuts)+3-1, "RdYlGn")
print( 
spplot(as(r, 'SpatialGridDataFrame'),at=cuts,
col.regions=col.regions,
colorkey=list(labels=list(at=cuts),at=cuts), pretty=TRUE,
scales=list(draw=T)
) 
)

## 2. spatial map with ggplot
p = rasterToPoints(r); df = data.frame(p)
colnames(df) = c("x", "y", "NDVI")

p  <- ggplot(data=df) + geom_tile(aes(x, y, fill=NDVI)) +
coord_equal() + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) + 
scale_fill_gradient2(low="red", mid="yellow",high="green",
limits=c(minValue(r),maxValue(r)), midpoint = 0.4) + theme_bw() +
scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
print(p)
```

ssplot() result
[image: ssplot]

ggplot() result
[image: ggplot]

Comment: Please don't use red-green colour contrasts.  The 5-10% of men with red-green colour weakness will find them [very hard to read](http://vischeck.homeip.net/uploads/131191118210660/).

Comment: the link to Koske's site - illustrates more or less what I would like to do. I'll explore ggplot() capacity further, adjust colors,improve legend and post an update below. All tips/examples are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks @joran for the pointer to that.

here is an example code and output using the dev version:

```
br <- seq(min(df$NDVI), max(df$NDVI), len=8)

ggplot(data=df) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x, y, fill=NDVI)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="green", 
    breaks=br, labels=sprintf("%.02f", br), 
    guide=guide_colorbar(title=NULL, nbin=100, barheight=unit(0.75, "npc"), label.hjust=1)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

you can probably try this by:

```
# from Hadley's instruction
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
dev_mode() # to avoid interfering with your existing install
install_github("ggplot2", username="kohske", branch = "feature/new-guides-with-gtable")
library(ggplot2)
```

UPDATED:

here is the instruction for the installation from scratch:

```
install.packages(
  c('devtools', 'digest', 'memoise', 'plyr', 'reshape2', 'RColorBrewer', 'stringr', 'dichromat', 'munsell', 'plyr', 'colorspace'), 
  dep=TRUE)

library(devtools)
dev_mode()

install_github("scales")
install_github("ggplot2", username="kohske", branch = "feature/new-guides-with-gtable")
```

Comment: I just tried it but I get the following error: when building ‘ggplot2_0.9.0.tar.gz’
ERROR: dependency ‘scales’ is not available for package ‘ggplot2’, it says that scales is not available for 2.13.0 where can I find it? It would be great to make legends such as the one above. Great.

Comment: I found scales on github https://github.com/hadley/scales, what is the best way to install this in R?

Comment: The answer was updated. try `install_github("scales")`. if you get errors such as missing packages `RColorBrewer, stringr, dichromat, munsell, plyr, colorspace`, then try `install.packages(c('RColorBrewer', 'stringr', 'dichromat', 'munsell', 'plyr', 'colorspace'), dep=TRUE)`

Comment: thanks great! this works well. I will now try to improve the colors so that different levels have clear colors (regarding the remark of Hadley.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how to address (1) off the top of my head. But here are some possible solutions for (2) and (3).

I don't believe that `ggplot2` currently is capable of labeling the legend in that manner. However, Koske has been working on some code that may be rolled into `ggplot2` in the future that creates legends that are styled in this manner. [Here](http://kohske.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/alpha-version-of-colorbar-legend-in-ggplot2/) is a link, although it will require installing some additional packages and is only alpha.

To get the specific breaks you're looking for, try this:

```
br <- c(-0.25,-0.05,0.15,0.35,0.56,0.76,0.96,1.16)
p  <- ggplot(data=df) + geom_tile(aes(x, y, fill=NDVI)) +
coord_equal() + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) + 
scale_fill_gradient(low="red", mid="yellow",high="green",
breaks = br) + theme_bw() +
scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
print(p)
```

which produced this graph on my machine:

[image]

I have not tested what this would look like using the experimental code mentioned above.

Comment: The only way I can think of to get a high-to-low legend without hacking the internals of the ggplot code is to make the scale into a factor with `cut`, assign the colours by hand, and reverse the order of the levels ...

Comment: thanks for the link too the site of Koske, that is precisely what I would like to do with the legend of a ggplot spatial map. I'll do some testing a will post a final result below soon.

Comment: note that the codes are outdated. Please find this post to ggplot2 list: http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/1026e8bf330deca2

Answer (score 0):

Re: (2)
First `cut()` your data to get a binned dataset. Use `breaks` and `labels` options in `cut()` to obtain the correct labels, e.g.:

```
dat$col <- cut(
  df$NDVI, 
  breaks=c(-Inf, -0.25, 0.05, ...whatever..., Inf), 
  labels=c(-0.25, 0.05, ...whatever..., "")
)
```

Then you can plot using ggplot and shifting the labels so that they are right on the color boudaries using:

```
 scale_fill_manual (your options...) + guides(fill=guide_legend(label.vjust = 1.2)) #1.2= what fits your legend best. Use label.hjust if using an horizontal color bar
```

See also:
[Generating a color legend with shifted labels using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802272/generating-a-color-legend-with-shifted-labels-using-ggplot2)

Alternatively, you can create the color legend with an external script (e.g. GrADS makes nice color legends using the right scripts) and specify the same colors manually in scale_fill_manual.