# Create discrete color bar with varying interval widths and no spacing between legend levels

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I'd like to reproduce this color scale in `ggplot2`:
[image]
([Source](https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-1-897aa8f8ca2c))

In the past I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802272/generating-a-color-legend-with-shifted-labels-using-ggplot2) that creating discrete color scales with labels in-between in `ggplot2` can be tricky.

Can this be accomplished at all? A similar, but not completely identical question I have recently posed is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506696/steeper-gradients-in-scale-gradientn) one.

Comment: Possibly related/helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487369/ggplot-set-scale-color-gradientn-manually?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Another possibly helpful thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352412/how-do-you-create-a-gradient-of-colors-for-a-discrete-variable-in-ggplot2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: isn't it sth. like `scale_color_gradient2(low="yellow",mid = "orange",high = "red",midpoint = 1000)`?

Comment: @Tjebo this would involve modifying the `ggplot` source code tho, something that is way above my capabilities unfortunately.

Comment: For future searches to answer the question how to position the label in the middle of the bins https://stackoverflow.com/a/67358007/7941188

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following answer is sufficiently different to merit a second answer. ggplot2 has massively changed in the last 2 years (!), and there are now new functions such as `scale_..._binned`, and specific gradient creating functions such as `scale_..._fermenter`

This has made the creation of a discrete gradient bar fairly straight forward.

For a "full separator" instead of ticks, see [user teunbrands post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62558606/7941188).

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Petal.Length))+
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_fermenter(breaks = c(1:3,5,7), palette = "Reds") + 
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(
    ticks = TRUE, 
    even.steps = FALSE,
    frame.linewidth = 0.55, 
    frame.colour = "black", 
    ticks.colour = "black",
    ticks.linewidth = 0.3)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

EDIT: since [ggplot 3.3.0](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/), binned scales are now built-in to ggplot. This answer is obsolete, refer to tjebo's [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62556763/4124334) for a more detailed example.

Thanks to [Tjebo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50518287/4124334), I managed to create a function that plots a nice colorbar, to be added to plots by using `cowplot`, `patchwork` or other similar packages like in his example.

Here it is:
EDIT: you can find it also on [github](https://github.com/adrfantini/plot_discrete_cbar)

```
plot_discrete_cbar = function(
    breaks, # Vector of breaks. If +-Inf are used, triangles will be added to the sides of the color bar
    palette = "Greys", # RColorBrewer palette to use
    colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(length(breaks) - 1, palette), # Alternatively, manually set colors
    direction = 1, # Flip colors? Can be 1 or -1
    spacing = "natural", # Spacing between labels. Can be "natural" or "constant"
    border_color = NA, # NA = no border color
    legend_title = NULL,
    legend_direction = "horizontal", # Can be "horizontal" or "vertical"
    font_size = 5,
    expand_size = 1, # Controls spacing around legend plot
    spacing_scaling = 1, # Multiplicative factor for label and legend title spacing
    width = 0.1, # Thickness of color bar
    triangle_size = 0.1 # Relative width of +-Inf triangles
) {
    require(ggplot2)
    if (!(spacing %in% c("natural", "constant"))) stop("spacing must be either 'natural' or 'constant'")
    if (!(direction %in% c(1, -1))) stop("direction must be either 1 or -1")
    if (!(legend_direction %in% c("horizontal", "vertical"))) stop("legend_direction must be either 'horizontal' or 'vertical'")
    breaks = as.numeric(breaks)
    new_breaks = sort(unique(breaks))
    if (any(new_breaks != breaks)) warning("Wrong order or duplicated breaks")
    breaks = new_breaks
    if (class(colors) == "function") colors = colors(length(breaks) - 1)
    if (length(colors) != length(breaks) - 1) stop("Number of colors (", length(colors), ") must be equal to number of breaks (", length(breaks), ") minus 1")
    if (!missing(colors)) warning("Ignoring RColorBrewer palette '", palette, "', since colors were passed manually")

    if (direction == -1) colors = rev(colors)

    inf_breaks = which(is.infinite(breaks))
    if (length(inf_breaks) != 0) breaks = breaks[-inf_breaks]
    plotcolors = colors

    n_breaks = length(breaks)

    labels = breaks

    if (spacing == "constant") {
        breaks = 1:n_breaks
    }

    r_breaks = range(breaks)

    cbar_df = data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
        y = breaks,
        yend = c(breaks[-1], NA),
        color = as.character(1:n_breaks)
    )[-n_breaks,]

    xmin = 1 - width/2
    xmax = 1 + width/2

    cbar_plot = ggplot(cbar_df, aes(xmin=xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = y, ymax = yend, fill = factor(color, levels = 1:length(colors)))) +
        geom_rect(show.legend = FALSE,
                  color=border_color)

    if (any(inf_breaks == 1)) { # Add < arrow for -Inf
        firstv = breaks[1]
        polystart = data.frame(
            x = c(xmin, xmax, 1),
            y = c(rep(firstv, 2), firstv - diff(r_breaks) * triangle_size)
        )
        plotcolors = plotcolors[-1]
        cbar_plot = cbar_plot +
            geom_polygon(data=polystart, aes(x=x, y=y),
                        show.legend = FALSE,
                        inherit.aes = FALSE,
                        fill = colors[1],
                        color=border_color)
    }
    if (any(inf_breaks > 1)) { # Add > arrow for +Inf
        lastv = breaks[n_breaks]
        polyend = data.frame(
            x = c(xmin, xmax, 1),
            y = c(rep(lastv, 2), lastv + diff(r_breaks) * triangle_size)
        )
        plotcolors = plotcolors[-length(plotcolors)]
        cbar_plot = cbar_plot +
            geom_polygon(data=polyend, aes(x=x, y=y),
                        show.legend = FALSE,
                        inherit.aes = FALSE,
                        fill = colors[length(colors)],
                        color=border_color)
    }

    if (legend_direction == "horizontal") { #horizontal legend
        mul = 1
        x = xmin
        xend = xmax
        cbar_plot = cbar_plot + coord_flip()
        angle = 0
        legend_position = xmax + 0.1 * spacing_scaling
    } else { # vertical legend
        mul = -1
        x = xmax
        xend = xmin
        angle = -90
        legend_position = xmax + 0.2 * spacing_scaling
    }

    cbar_plot = cbar_plot +
        geom_segment(data=data.frame(y = breaks, yend = breaks),
            aes(y=y, yend=yend),
            x = x - 0.05 * mul * spacing_scaling, xend = xend,
            inherit.aes = FALSE) +
        annotate(geom = 'text', x = x - 0.1 * mul * spacing_scaling, y = breaks,
                label = labels,
                size = font_size) +
        scale_x_continuous(expand = c(expand_size,expand_size)) +
        scale_fill_manual(values=plotcolors) +
        theme_void()

    if (!is.null(legend_title)) { # Add legend title
        cbar_plot = cbar_plot +
            annotate(geom = 'text', x = legend_position, y = mean(r_breaks),
                label = legend_title,
                angle = angle,
                size = font_size)
    }

    cbar_plot
}
```

Example usage:

`plot_discrete_cbar(c(1:10))`

[image]

`plot_discrete_cbar(c(0,2,5,10,20, Inf), palette="Reds")`

[image]

`plot_discrete_cbar(c(0,2,5,10,20, Inf), colors=rainbow, legend_direction="vertical", legend_title="A title! WOW!", border_color="red")`

[image]

`plot_discrete_cbar(c(-Inf, -8, -4, -2, -1, 1, 2, 4, 8, Inf), palette="BrBG", legend_title="Precipitation bias (mm/day)")`

[image]

`plot_discrete_cbar(c(-Inf, -8, -4, -2, -1, 1, 2, 4, 8, Inf), palette="BrBG", legend_title="Precipitation bias (mm/day)", spacing="constant")`

[image]

Comment: @Tjebo Thanks! I've asked Hadley in the past to implement something like this (but way more refined, as a built-in type of color guide), but he said that the usecase was not compelling enough. I'll get around to opening a more detailed issue sooner or later, showing how most other plotting systems allow for this kind of color bar.

Comment: @Tjebo good news! Hadley said this kind of scales could be incorporated in ggplot! https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2673

Comment: @tjebo sorry, That was not my intention. There is now a better answer (using the new ggplot built-ins), which I added to my own (at the beginning, with an edit). I don't know which is the right procedure in this case, should I create a new answer?

Comment: @tjebo, oh right, I got confused too. So I accepted your second answer and will add an edit to my own pointing to it!

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by [@Henrik 's answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49077005/7941188), a possible workaround is to make a plot that looks like a legend :)

```
require(ggplot2)
require(cowplot)


values <- c(0,1,2,5,10) # this vector is needed not only for the data frame cbar, but also for plotting
group <- letters[1:5]
diff_values <- c(0, diff(values))
cbar_df <- data.frame(x = 1, y = values, diff_values,group,  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#that's for the fake legend

iris2 <- iris #don't want to mess with your iris data set
              #I used iris because you hadn't provided data
iris2$cuts <- cut(iris2$Petal.Length, values) #the already offered 'cut-approach' 


p1  <- ggplot(iris2, aes(Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = cuts))+ 
          geom_point() +
          scale_color_brewer("", palette = "Reds")

cbar_plot <- ggplot(cbar_df, aes(x, y = diff_values, fill = c(NA, rev(group[2:5])))) + 
  # I had to do implement this 'fill=' workaround 
  # in creating a new vector introducing an NA, 
  # and I had to flip the fills in order to fit to the scale... 
    geom_col(width = 0.1, show.legend = FALSE)  +
    geom_segment(y = values, yend = values, x = 0.9, xend = 1.05) +
    annotate(geom = 'text', x = 0.85, y = values, label = values) +
  # the numbers are quasi-randomly chosen but define the length of your ticks, obviously
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(1,1)) + 
  # you might need to play around with the expand argument for the width of your legend
    scale_fill_brewer("", palette = "Reds", direction = -1) +  
  # don't know why you have to flip this again... 
    coord_flip() +
    theme_void()

plot_grid(p1, cbar_plot, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

I mean - there is certainly a lot of room for improvement (making the legend plot smaller etc...). But what do you think?

```
#P.S. 
sessionInfo() 
cowplot_0.9.2 ggplot2_2.2.1
```

Comment: Very interesting solution. Combining plots in `ggplot` is always a bit tricky, since spacing, alignement etc. always pose some problems... but this is really a great start. Do you think this solution could be encompassed in a generic function, or does it require too much playing around with the numerical constants you used (e.g. `expand`)?

Comment: What about "Create discrete color bar with varying interval widths?"

Comment: I'm working on a function to generalize this solution.

Comment: I have conjured together this: https://pastebin.com/Yw78bC0A. It works beautifully. Do you mind if I paste and accept an answer with that content, mentioning yours?

Comment: Am at the beach, so cannot check this right now :D Sure go for it. But I would recommend a better function name - as recommended by Hadley etc, I would suggest using a verb for the name, which tells what the function is doing. Such as “create_cbar_discrete” (odd name, was just an example)

Comment: Yeah, that weird function name was definitely just a placeholder :)

Comment: posted an answer, see if you like it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try. For the first answer see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802272/generating-a-color-legend-with-shifted-labels-using-ggplot2/50512576#50512576)

```
# data
set.seed(1324)
dat <- data.frame(x=0:100, y=runif(101, 0, 10), z=seq(0, 12, len=101))
# add discrete values
dat$col <- cut(include.lowest = T,
  dat$z, 
  breaks=c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, max(dat$z)), 
  labels=c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
)
# Discete
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y,fill=col)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col=col),size=8, show.legend = F) +   
  geom_col(alpha=0)+
  scale_fill_brewer("", palette = "Reds")+
  scale_colour_brewer("", palette="Reds")+
  scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(0,1))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow=1,override.aes = list(alpha = 1), 
                             label.position="bottom",
                             label.hjust = -0.05)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        legend.key.width = unit(3, "cm"), 
        legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"))
```

[image]

```
# Continuous
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y,color=y)) + 
  geom_point(size=8) +   
  scale_colour_continuous("",limits=c(0,10), 
                          breaks=c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10),low = "white", high = "red")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        legend.key.width = unit(3, "cm"), 
        legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is not much different from what I already stated in the question, as you can see the "found" link. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
scale_fill_gradientn (guide = guide_colourbar(nbin = 255))
```

to achieve.

you can set nbin to whatever you like.