# How to make a banner/coloured box with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a box with a colour gradient (discrete or continuous) as shown in the picture below with *ggplot2* in *R*. The colour in the box shows how close points are fitted, i.e. values are given in a simple vector. The box should appear right below my plot.
Can anybody give a hint how such a box can be built?
 [image]

Comment: have a look at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506832/create-discrete-color-bar-with-varying-interval-widths-and-no-spacing-between-le/50518287#50518287) It might contain what you want. Basically, it is about using `geom_rect`

Comment: This can be useful too https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2673#issuecomment-402878574