# R: Extended/tapered colour bar using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbar

Is there a way to format the colour bar in ggplot2 so that it is tapered at one or both ends, similar to e.g. matplotlib? 
This shows that all values that are smaller/larger than the zlim minimum/maximum are represented by this colour on e.g a heatmap.

[Matplotlib example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AypAJ.png)

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506832/create-discrete-color-bar-with-varying-interval-widths-and-no-spacing-between-le/50540633#50540633

Comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2673#issuecomment-402878574

Comment: Thanks a lot – didn't manage to find the previous post on this sorry.