# How to show the color and opacity in legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

This is a plot that I'm trying to create like the one that was shown in [nytimes](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/02/23/business/economy/the-changing-nature-of-middle-class-jobs.html).

**My code**:

```
ggplot(gwsj, aes(x = Year, y = Freq, color = Gender)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1.2, aes(alpha = Functn)) + 
  geom_point(aes(alpha = Functn)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Female" = "#d81b60", "Male" = "#1976d2")) +
  facet_wrap(~OrgType, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_pubclean()
```

**What I get**:

[image]

**What I want**

The scale that shows the `gender` count and the `Functn` legend with colors and opacity like the ones shown in nytimes. I've tried many things, but I'm missing something somewhere

Comment: It doesn't seem like the nytimes plot encodes anything in the opacity, and I don't exactly get why you are encoding a categorical variable as opacity. Would you explain what exactly you think is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: It's not that it's wrong, just wanted to identify which `Functn` is which. Right now, this plots only shows the `gender` and the opacity would be the `Functn`. What I really want is the distribution of the gender across Functn. I hope this is clear

Comment: As far as I get it, the nytimes plot simply maps the share of females/males, i.e. a continous variable, for different occupations on color which automatically results in the kind of gradient color scale. However, which occupation (which as I got it  correpsonds to your `Functn`) corresponds to which line is not visible from the plot. That's why they added the annotations for some example occupations.

Comment: I think the nytimes plot is very convoluted and I don't know if I would try to reproduce it. ... FYI, They have a "discrete continuous scale", which is *not* an inbuilt feature of ggplot. [But there is a solution for this, see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506832/create-discrete-color-bar-with-varying-interval-widths-and-no-spacing-between-le/50518287#50518287)