# Continuous scale fill gradientn with fixed cutoffs R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient

I can't figure out how to define fixed cutoffs in a gradient fill.
[This is an example on the iris data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Zmk.png)

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length,
                 y=Sepal.Width,
                 fill=Petal.Length))+
  geom_point(shape=21)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=c("white","black","darkred","red"))
```

In my actual data, I have a heatmap with many values 0, a lot between 1-10, a few outliers in the hundreds and thousands.

I would like the gradient to be:

- 0 = white
- 1-10 = from gray to black
- 11-100 = from black to darkred
- 101-1000 = from darkred to red
- over 1000 = purple

I don't want to transform it in a factor with bins, because I do want to maintain the continuous gradient especially at the low parts of the scale.

Thank you for you help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create discrete color bar with varying interval widths and no spacing between legend levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506832/create-discrete-color-bar-with-varying-interval-widths-and-no-spacing-between-le)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to generate you own color pal with `colorspace` for the white to red, but if you're okay with the default blues or viridis, you can have that out of the box with `scale_fill_binned()`:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length,
                 y=Sepal.Width,
                 fill=Petal.Length))+
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4) +
  scale_fill_binned(breaks = c(2, 5), type = "viridis")
```

[image]

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_coloursteps.html